# Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 FTP Server Doesn't Work

Tags: webserver, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-firewall, ftp

I have a newly installed W2K8 R2 which I use it as web server.

I have already enabled all the things under the "web server(IIS)" and I also checked that the Windows Firewall had all the FTP-related inbound and outbound rules enabled.

However, I still cannot ftp to this W2K8 server from other machines and even on this machine itself, every time I typed in "open [local ip addr]" in ftp session in cmd, it didn't show any error msg such that it cannot connect to the ip addr but when I typed in "dir" it poped up a msg saying "not connected".

I need your help please.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you created and configured an FTP site? IIRC, the default website that IIS creates is just that, a website. You'll need to create an FTP site (or add FTP publishing to an existing website) to be able to use FTP.

Comment: @Indrek I haven't created and configured any FTP "website" yet. Since I just use this server to store files and whenever another server need any files it can ftp to this server to get the filer directly through the cmd or terminal. Thanks.

Comment: Not "FTP website", just "FTP site". It's just like a website, except it serves files of the FTP protocol instead of HTTP/HTTPS. At least one FTP site is required if you want to use your computer as an FTP server.

Comment: May be a better question for serverfault.

Comment: @Jeff F. you are right....because there are too many "sub-websites" of StackExchange....I will post to the most-related website if I have new questions next time. Thanks.

Comment: @user990106 no problem :). You'll find people more willing to tackle server questions there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use your computer as an FTP server, you'll need to add and configure an FTP site. Just like a website tells IIS which folder to serve files (and execute scripts) from in response to which HTTP requests, an FTP site tells IIS the same thing for FTP requests. A single site can act as both an FTP site and a website, if you add multiple protocol bindings to it.

To add an FTP site, start IIS manager as usual, right-click on "Sites" and select "Add FTP Site...". The configuration is pretty similar to creating a website - you'll need to enter a descriptive name, the physical path where the files are stored, create bindings that determine how clients will access this FTP site, and set authentication options.

For a more detailed tutorial, see [Creating a New FTP Site in IIS 7](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/301/creating-a-new-ftp-site-in-iis-7) (applies to IIS 7.5 as well).